# How to calculate the fair price of an option using Black-Scholes model in Julia?

Tags: julia, finance

In python, option price can be calculated using:

```
from math import *
def bs_call(S,X,T,r,sigma):
    d1 = (log(S/X)+(r+sigma*sigma/2.)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1-sigma*sqrt(T)
    return S*CND(d1)-X*exp(-r*T)*CND(d2)
```

Please guide me in doing it (prefer to use built in function, if any) julia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`BS.jl`](https://github.com/felipenoris/BS.jl) package - the readme shows how to use it. Note that it is not registered so you have to `]add https://github.com/felipenoris/BS.jl` to add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following if you prefer to do it with your own function:

```
using Distributions
N(x) = cdf(Normal(0,1),x)

# generic put call pricer (cp = call_put_flag, 1 = call -1 = put)
function BSM(S,K,t,rf,d,σ, cp)
    d1 = ( log(S/K) + (rf - d + 1/2*σ^2)*t ) / (σ*sqrt(t))
    d2 = d1 - σ*sqrt(t)
    opt  = cp*exp(-d*t)S*N(cp*d1) - cp*exp(-rf*t)*K*N(cp*d2)
  return opt
end
```

[image]
which matches Bloomberg OVME quite well:

[image]